# How to count the pixels of a certain color with OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to calculate the percentage of pixels in a certain color range in a picture.

I'm pretty new to OpenCV and python in general. What I've done is using the `cv2.inRange()` function to create a mask which I have as output. Right now I'm trying to do this with GRB color values between (0, 0, 130) and (80, 80, 255) and consider "red" every pixel whose color is in this range. So the output I get has two colors: black and red. 
I used then this numpy function to get the number of non zero pixels which at this point I expected to be the number of red pixels: `red_pixel = np.count_nonzero(output)`.

Here is the full code:

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img_name = input("What's the name of the picture? ")


img = cv2.imread(img_name)

# boundaries for the color red
boundaries = [
    ([0, 0, 130], [80, 80, 255])
    ]

for(lower, upper) in boundaries:
    # creates numpy array from boundaries
    lower = np.array(lower, dtype = "uint8")
    upper = np.array(upper, dtype = "uint8")

    # finds colors in boundaries a applies a mask
    mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
    output = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = mask)

    # saves the image
    cv2.imwrite('2'+img_name, output)

tot_pixel = output.size
red_pixel = np.count_nonzero(output)
percentage = round(red_pixel * 100 / tot_pixel, 2)

print("Red pixels: " + str(red_pixel))
print("Total pixels: " + str(tot_pixel))
print("Percentage of red pixels: " + str(percentage) + "%")
```

I tested my code with four different pictures:

[sea.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPgsq.jpg)
which I'd expect to contain 0% of red. I run the program, as output I get a completely black image and the percentage is 0.00. Which is fine.

I tried then this one:

[sample.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDtc0.jpg)
I run the program and what I get for the percentage is 13.76 which I don't know if it's correct but could still be.

I tried a completely red image then: [total-red.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGXYy.jpg)
and I get 100.00 which is correct.

The strange thing happens when I try with this image:
[almost-red.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWAxb.png)

What I get running the program is this output:
[2almost-red.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VK3e.png)
which is what I expected. The percentage of non zero pixels though, is 33.07%
and I have no idea why.

Could you please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong and how I could correct the program? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image has three channels. Only one channel is in range in your third example almost-red.png.
Thus we can deduct that at most 33% of the image is in range. As there is some border it has to be even less. 33.07% sounds plausible.

If you want to check if any of the channels for each pixel is in range you have to sum up the three channels and than check for non-zero entries.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, could you please suggest me a way to sum the three channels?

Comment: `summed = np.sum(output, axis=2)` should do the trick. Do it before counting the total pixels.